# Using Random Pointers to copy linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Problem Statement : A linked list is given such that each node contains an additional random pointer which could point to any node in the list or null. Return a deep copy of the list. 
[original problem link](https://leetcode.com/problems/copy-list-with-random-pointer/)

I have two very similar solutions , one which gets accepted while other has error.

Code1 (Accepted Solution)

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list with a random pointer.
 * struct RandomListNode {
 *     int label;
 *     RandomListNode *next, *random;
 *     RandomListNode(int x) : label(x), next(NULL), random(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
   RandomListNode *copyRandomList(RandomListNode *head) 
    {
        if(head == NULL)
            return head;
        RandomListNode *h1 = head,*h2=NULL;
        while(h1!=NULL)
        {
            h2=new RandomListNode(h1->label);
            h2->next=h1->random;
            h1->random=h2;
            h1=h1->next;
        }
        h1=head;
        while(h1!=NULL)
        {
            h2=h1->random;
            if(h2->next != NULL)
                h2->random=h2->next->random;
            else
                h2->random=NULL;

            h1=h1->next;
        }
        h1=head;
        head=h1->random;
        while(h1!=NULL)
        {
            h2=h1->random;
            h1->random=h2->next;
            if(h1->next!=NULL)
                h2->next=h1->next->random;
            else
                h2->next=NULL;
            h1=h1->next;
        }

        return head;
    }
};
```

Code2 :(Gives Wrong Answer)

```
class Solution {
public:
   RandomListNode *copyRandomList(RandomListNode *head) 
    {
        if(head == NULL)
            return head;
        RandomListNode *h1 = head,*h2=NULL;
        while(h1!=NULL)
        {
            h2=new RandomListNode(h1->label);
            h2->next=h1->random;
            h1->random=h2;
            h1=h1->next;
        }
        h1=head;
        head=h1->random;
        while(h1!=NULL)
        {
            h2=h1->random;
            if(h2->next != NULL)
                h2->random=h2->next->random;
            else
                h2->random=NULL;

            /*MERGED LAST WHILE LOOP FROM HERE*/

            h1->random=h2->next;
            if(h1->next!=NULL)
                h2->next=h1->next->random;
            else
                h2->next=NULL;
            h1=h1->next;
        }


        return head;
    }
};
```

The second code gives an error that :- Random pointer of node in new list points to a node from the original list. But here i had to generate a new and an exact clone of original linked list.
I have simply merged last two while loops in one loop.I am unable to figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: So have you stepped through the code in a debugger, line-by-line, and examined the variable values, etc?  That is the first thing to do/